# Video is downloaded instead of being displayed on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, object, video, iframe, embed

I have created as simple aspx page on visual studio 2010 with targetFrameWork=4.0 that displays videos of types mp4 or wmv, I have tried this code but whenever I open the page the video is downloaded not displayed why?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe width="560" 
                height="315" 
                src="Wildlife.wmv" 
                frameborder="0" 
                allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**
I have tried also this:

```
<object type="video/mp4" data="TEST VIDEO.mp4" width="420" height="340">
                 <param name="url" value="video\TEST VIDEO.mp4"/>
                 <param name="src" value="video\TEST VIDEO.mp4" />
                 <param name="autostart" value="true" />
                 <param name="sound" value="true" />
                 <param name="controller" value="true" />
</object>
```

and this:

```
<embed src="TEST VIDEO.mp4" ></embed>
```

Same issue ... :(

Comment: Is the server configured with the correct Content-Type (mime) value for mp4 files?

Comment: @szatmary thank you for your reply,how can I check it?